# influx: all old data got deleted after applying retention policy

Tags: influxdb

I had data from last 7 days in influx. I applied retention policy and suddenly all data got deleted. i have single instance of influx running.

```
CREATE RETENTION POLICY stats_30_day ON server_stats DURATION 30d REPLICATION 1

ALTER RETENTION POLICY stats_30_day ON server_stats DURATION 30d REPLICATION 1 default
```

Any idea what went wrong ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You changed what your default retention policy is. So when you query you'll have to specify the other retention policy. See:
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/troubleshooting/frequently_encountered_issues/#missing-data-after-creating-a-new-default-retention-policy